# pause functionality in rosbag play?

Tags: ros, rosbag, play

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rosbag wiki says 'The main new feature being planned for rosbag is the addition of a ROS API for interacting with the playing and recording nodes via service calls.'... I was wondering what the status on this is? Will this be added any time soon?

At the moment I am running rosbag play through the roslaunch api, and I would like to have a way to pause/resume the playback through a GUI I have. Apparently, by running the rosbag application externally, you can press space to pause, but this does not really work for me. Any ideas how to do this? For instance like sending a 'space' input to the rosbag node...?

For the record I am using python at the moment.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28798/pause-functionality-in-rosbag-play?/) by [rune](https://answers.ros.org/users/1217/rune/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-02-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rune](https://answers.ros.org/users/1217/rune/) on 2012-02-29**:
If anyone else is interested, as a temporary solution, I ended up spawning rosbag by using p = subprocess.Popen() and p.stdin.write(). This works, but a rosbag API would still be preferred :)

**Comment by [MrRivi](https://answers.ros.org/users/56048/mrrivi/) on 2020-08-25**:
Although this question is old: after playing the rosbag, a service for pause-playback is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could have a look how [rxbag](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rxbag) implements that. I believe they analyze the bag file and do play/stop themselves, but I'm not sure about that, I never used it.

Maybe it helps... :)

---

Originally posted by [Felix Kaser](https://answers.ros.org/users/2655/felix-kaser/) with karma: 318 on 2012-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1